# Named entity recognition for Arabic corpus using Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I wish to find out how to use Stanford NER to train a corpus in Arabic. I was hoping to use freely available corpus such as ANERCorp available here :

http://www1.ccls.columbia.edu/~ybenajiba/downloads.html

I used the following prop file:

```
trainFile = ANERCorp
serializeTo = aner-model.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1
maxLeft=1
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useDisjunctive=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
```

I then trained the model using:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop t.prop
```

The training ran successfully and was serialized to my model. But when I test the model I always get a blank dataset, i.e. no entity is recognised. I know I am testing it the correct way because I am able to test English text on English models following the same methodology successfully.

Are there any properties I need to set in the prop file specifically for Arabic language? Has anyone tried training an arabic ner on Stanford NLP before? I know this has been done using LingPipe but I would prefer to stick with SNLP.

Comment: Arabic is a very different language and script, you need some special features to deal with this language. The stanford-nlp site does not claim that stanford-ner supports Arabic language, though their word segmentation and POS tagger support arabic. See: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/